# wordpress adding product attributes hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

I have 1 attribute called Weight in Products > Attributes. I have a nice hierarchy in here and its organized like the picture below.

Organized attributes: [image]

My problem is when you go to add a new product and under attributes I added my attribute called weight. But in the select dropdown there its not organized. See the image below for the unorganized select list of attributes when adding a product.

Unorganized attributes: [image]

How can I get my select list when adding a product to look like the one that is under Products > Attributes? Or, how can I get image #2 to look like image #1?